# Difficulty with mutation involving classes

Tags: c++, pointers, mutators

I have a class, `characterData`, and a list of this type:

```
class characterData {
    private:
        vector<vector<int> > pixelData;
        int area;
    public:
        void setPix(vector<vector<int> > in) {
            pixelData = in;
            area = in.size() * in[0].size();
        }
        vector<vector<int> > getPix() {
            return pixelData;
        }
        int getArea() {
            return area;
        }
};

list<characterData> listChars;
```

I'm trying to mutate `pixelData` in other methods, but keep running into issues. I have a method which does some function to `pixelData`:

```
void processHandler(list<characterData> &inList) {
    while (!inList.empty()) {
        normalize(inList.front().getPix());
        inList.pop_front();
    }
}

void normalize(vector<vector<int> > &input) {
    if (input.size() > input[0].size()) {
        affixRows(input, input.size() - input[0].size());
    } else if (input.size() > input[0].size()) {
        affixCols(input, input[0].size() - input.size());
    }
}

void affixRows(vector<vector<int>> &input, int dimDiff) {
    vector<vector<int>> temp(input.size(), vector<int>(input[0].size() + dimDiff));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < temp[0].size(); i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++) {
            if (i < (unsigned int)dimDiff / 2) {
                temp[j][i] = 255;
            }
            else if (i < input[0].size() + (int)dimDiff / 2) {
                temp[j][i] = input[j][i - (int)dimDiff / 2];
            }
            else {
                temp[j][i] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
    input = temp; // point of mutation
}

void affixCols(vector<vector<int>> &input, int dimDiff) {
    vector<vector<int>> temp(input.size() + dimDiff, vector<int>(input[0].size()));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < temp[0].size(); i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++) {
            if (j < (unsigned int)dimDiff / 2) {
                temp[j][i] = 255;
            }
            else if (j < input.size() + (int)dimDiff / 2) {
                temp[j][i] = input[j - (int)dimDiff / 2][i];
            }
            else {
                temp[j][i] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
    input = temp; // point of mutation
}
```

I get these errors:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::vector<std::vector<int> >&' from an rvalue of type 'std::vector<std::vector<int> >'
normalize(inList.front().getPix());
-------------------------------^--
```

If instead of:

```
normalize(inList.front().getPix());
```

I make a temporary vector and use that, it goes without error.

```
vector<vector<int> > temp = inList.front().getPix();
normalize(temp);
```

But this won't accomplish what I want, which is mutating the `pixelData` of a `characterData`. Why can I not access `pixelData` directly for the purpose of mutation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up the use of pointers and references.

In the function `void processHandler(list<characterData> *inList)`, `inList` is a pointer, but the code within the function uses it as a reference.

```
while (!inList.empty())
{
    normalize(inList.front().getPix());
    inList.pop_front();
}
```

needs to treat `inList` as a pointer.  So replace `inList.` with `inList->`.

```
while (!inList->empty())
{
    normalize(inList->front().getPix());
    inList->pop_front();
}
```

This will give a second problem as `characterData::getPix()` returns by value. but `normalize()` expects a reference (so the compiler will complain about something akin to passing a reference to a temporary - the temporary holds the value returned by `getPix()`, which will be a copy of the `pixelData`).   Instead, to use it this way, `getPix()` needs to return a reference.

```
vector<vector<int> > &getPix() {return pixelData;}    // note the ampersand
```

This addresses your question AS ASKED.   More generally, your design is fatally flawed - a member function of `characterData` that provides direct access (by pointer or reference) to any `private` member is a bad idea, since it allows any code to change that member.    If you are going to do this, you might as well make the members `public` rather than `private`.

You need to provide member functions for `characterData` that allow a caller to REQUEST changes of `private` member functions (e.g. to add elements).   These functions can - if you choose - ignore such requests.   More importantly, they allow your class and its member functions, to collectively ensure the data is always in a valid state.   Which is not possible if a caller can make arbitrary changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getPix` method returns a temporary object.

```
vector<vector<int> > getPix() {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            return pixelData;
        }
```

You *may* want to return it by reference.